# Are the transformation matrices the relation between basis $\beta$ and $\beta'$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, change-of-basis

**Are the transformation matrices the relation between basis $\beta$ and $\beta'$?**

We are told to get the coordinates of vector  $v = (1,2,1)$ in both basis $\beta$ and $\beta'$, and find what the relation between the two basis is:

$$\beta = \{(1,1,-1),(0,-1,2),(2,0,1)\}$$

$$\beta' = \{(1,0,-1),(1,0,1),(0,1,1)\}$$

I get that the coordinates of the vector are:

$$M_\beta(v)= \left(
\begin{matrix}
9\\
7\\
-4\\
\end{matrix}\right) ,
M_\beta'(v)= \left(
\begin{matrix}
1\\
0\\
2\\
\end{matrix}\right)$$
And I get both transformation matrices:
$$M_{\beta}^{\beta'}= \left(
\begin{matrix}
3/2&-3/2&1/2\\
-1/2&3/2&3/2\\
1&-1&0\\
\end{matrix}\right) , M_{\beta'}^{\beta}= \left(
\begin{matrix}
-3&1&6\\
-3&1&5\\
2&0&-3\\
\end{matrix}\right)$$

I've tested that both transformation matrices work and also that I get $I_3$ when multiplying both of them:

$$M_\beta^{\beta'}.M_{\beta'}^{\beta} = I_3\\
M_\beta^{\beta'}.M_\beta(v) = M_{\beta'}(v)\\
M_{\beta'}^{\beta}.M_{\beta'}(v) = M_\beta(v)$$

Can I say that the transformation matrices are the relation between $\beta$ and $\beta'$?

Hope this is not a stupid question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose so.

Note that if you form the matrix consisting of the columns of $\mathcal B$ ($\mathcal B'$) you get the change of basis matrix from $\mathcal B$ (respectively $\mathcal B'$) to the standard basis.   Thus we should have:$$[I]_{\mathcal B}^{\mathcal B'}=[I]_S^{\mathcal B'}[I]_{\mathcal B}^S=\begin {pmatrix}1&1&0\\0&0&1\\-1&1&1\end{pmatrix}^{-1}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}1&0&2\\1&-1&0\\-1&2&1\end{pmatrix}$$. This should be your $[M]_{\mathcal B}^{\mathcal B'}$.  Indeed it is.

Comment: Wow I didnt know this way of getting the matrix, seems to be faster this way.

Comment: It's a good trick to know...

Comment: The thing is that you suppose that the answer to my question is yes, but you suppose it then I dont know what to do *~*

Comment: I guess you will find out in a matter of time.  I'm not sure what else they could be looking for.